# Error when using react and laravel mix

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm running into a problem when I'm trying to get react to work with my laravel project.

I'm using Homestead on windows. While ssh'd into my virtual server, and I'm in the root of my project I have run

```
composer install
php artisan preset react
npm install && npm run dev
```

I am then getting the following errors

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN img-loader@3.0.0 requires a peer of imagemin@^5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-92-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path ../acorn/bin/acorn
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/home/vagrant/www/todo/node_modules/.bin/acorn'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/www/todo/npm-debug.log
```

In my assets/js/components a react example.js has been added.

I'm not too sure where to go with this so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try with `npm install --no-bin-links`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with symbolic links creation between your host (windows) and VM.

First thing, you don't need to issue these commands via ssh, you can safely run them on your windows host (all changes will be silently copied back to your homestead VM machine - this is just how homestead works)

Secondly, depending on your VirtualBox installation some issues with symbolic links may arise. If that's the case, check if you are using the latest versions of VirtualBox and Homestead.

Then if still having problems, please check this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user?answertab=votes#125981)